# Why did adding an extra button to my React Form cause both my buttons to stop working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very much a novice at React and JavaScript, and have been trying to create a "Clear search filters" function in my App. I had already programmed the "Search with filters" portion of the code in the searchProgram function, which worked just fine. How it works: searchProgram is passed as a prop from App.js to SearchForm.js. On submission in the SearchForm, searchProgram is called in the handleSubmit function and it works just fine. However, upon addition of a new button called "Clear", both buttons have now stopped working. No error is produced as far as I can tell. Any tips on this would be appreciated. Thank you!

The below snippet is my App.js file, containing the searchProject function.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import LogIn from "./LogIn.js"
import User from "./components/User.js"
import Project from "./components/Project.js"
import CreateForm from "./CreateForm.js";
import DeleteForm from "./DeleteForm.js";
import SearchForm from "./SearchForm.js";
import JoinForm from "./JoinForm.js";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectList: [],
            searchProjects: [],
            userList: [],
            currentUser: "Guest",
            filterMode : false
        };

        this.logIn = this.logIn.bind(this);
        this.searchProject = this.searchProject.bind(this);
        this.joinProject = this.joinProject.bind(this);
        this.createProject = this.createProject.bind(this);
        this.deleteProject = this.deleteProject.bind(this);
        }

    logIn(name) {
        this.setState({
            currentUser : name
        })
    }    

    createProject(title, desc, langs, len, exp) {
        this.setState({
            projectList: [...this.state.projectList, {
                title : title,
                description : desc,
                language : langs,
                length : len,
                experience : exp,
                user : this.state.currentUser
            }]
        });
    }

    deleteProject(title) {
        const projects = this.state.projectList.filter(
            p => p.title !== title 
        );
        this.setState({projectList : projects});
    }

    searchProject(title, language, length, experience) {
        //added if else statement
        if ((title === "") && (language === "") && (length === 0) && (experience === "")) {
             this.setState({
                 filterMode : false
             })
        } else {
            let projects = [...this.state.projectList];
            if (title !== "") {
                projects = projects.filter(
                    p => p.title === title 
                );
            }
            if (language !== "") {
                projects = projects.filter(
                    p => p.language === language
                );
            }
            if (length !== 0) {
                projects = projects.filter(
                    p => p.length === length 
                );
            }
            if (experience !== "") {
                projects = projects.filter(
                    p => p.experience === experience
                );
            }
            this.setState({
                searchProjects : projects,
                filterMode : true
            });            
        }
    }

    joinProject(title) {
        let projects = [...this.state.projectList];
        if (title !== "") {
            projects = projects.filter(
                p => p.title === title 
            );
        }
        this.setState({projectList : projects});
    }


    render() {
        //added if else to render
        if (this.filterMode === true) {
            return(
                <div>
                    <User name = {this.state.currentUser} />
                    <LogIn logIn = {this.logIn} />
                    <CreateForm createProject = {this.createProject} />
                    <DeleteForm deleteProject = {this.deleteProject} />
                    <SearchForm searchProject = {this.searchProject} />
                    <JoinForm joinProject = {this.joinProject} />
                    <h1> Project List: </h1>
                    {this.state.searchProjects.map((params) =>
                    <Project key = {params.title} {...params} 
                    currentUser = {this.state.currentUser}/>)}
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return(
                <div>
                    <User name = {this.state.currentUser} />
                    <LogIn logIn = {this.logIn} />
                    <CreateForm createProject = {this.createProject} />
                    <DeleteForm deleteProject = {this.deleteProject} />
                    <SearchForm searchProject = {this.searchProject} />
                    <JoinForm joinProject = {this.joinProject} />
                    <h1> Project List: </h1>
                    {this.state.projectList.map((params) =>
                    <Project key = {params.title} {...params} />)}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    
}

export default App;
```

Below is the SearchForm.js file, which contains my filtering form. The new function added is called resetState, while the new button added was right before the input type = "submit" bit.

```js
import React from "react";

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        title: "",
        language: "",
        length: 0,
        experience: ""
      };
  
      this.resetState = this.resetState.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    //added resetState function
    resetState(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      this.props.searchProject(
        "",
        "",
        0,
        ""
      )

    }

    handleSubmit(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      this.props.searchProject(
        this.state.title,
        this.state.language,
        this.state.length,
        this.state.experience
      )
      
    }
  
    handleInputChange(event) {
      const target = event.target;
      const value = target.value;
      const name = target.name;
  
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <h2> Search Project: </h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Title:
                <input
                name="title"
                type="textbox"
                checked={this.state.title}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                Language:
                <input
                name="language"
                type="textbox"
                checked={this.state.language}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                Length:
                <input
                name="length"
                type="number"
                checked={this.state.length}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
                Experience:
                <input
                name="experience"
                type="textbox"
                checked={this.state.experience}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            //added button
            <button onClick={this.resetState}>
              Clear
            </button>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default SearchForm;
```

Comment: on resetState function you are trying to change the props value and not the local state.I think thats the reason you are thinking its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `render` method on `App` component, you are validating a class variable `this.filterMode` instead of the component `state`.

Try this:

App

```
render() {
 if (this.state.filterMode) {
  ...
 } else {
  ...
 }
}
```